# switching on/off second hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, fstab

I have installed a second hard disk (SATA spinning drive) with several partitions in my VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-X513EA-K513EA with an SSD drive.
Now I want this disk not to start and spinning when the laptop is booted. And if I used it, being able to stop it immediately.

I have Kubuntu 22.04 running, but will replace it due to high battery consumption.
(And I am close to take the drive out, putting it in an external case.)

I wonder what's the best way of controlling it,
since simply to set *noauto* in fstab has no effect.
Better  playing with *hdparm* ?

I have set one of the partitions to *noauto* but it's mounted after boot.

```
UUID=ea1983ab-90f0-423e-a090-2a71baeab82f   /media/Home/     ext4   noauto     0 0
```

For "historical" reasons I have mounted the partitions  in /media/xxx to maintain a certain file-path in a database  (but I can change it now).

Comment: `Now I want this disk not to start and spinning when the laptop is booted.` AFAIK that's not really possible, although you might be able have it spun down once the kernel and so have done probing it. (However apparently it is often tricky to *keep* it "asleep".) (There's something called Power-up in standby, PUIS, though, but IIRC it's something tricky to use too...)

Comment: Putting it in an external case is perhaps the only real solution.

Comment: Thank you guys.

Comment: `UUID` belongs to a filesystem; `PARTUUID` (if GPT) is written inside a partition table. You cannot read them without starting the disk. *In theory* it may be possible to get a serial number or "presence" from the electronics of the disk without spinning its platters, so `/dev/disk/by-id/…` or `/dev/disk/by-path/…` might work; and you would want a superfloppy to avoid relying on a node that requires reading the partition table from the disk. The kernel tries to read it automatically, so you would also need [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316026). But AFAIK disks do spin automatically.

Comment: Oh, big thanks for precise description @Kamil. "You cannot read them without starting the disk" That explains a lot to me...

Comment: I find the Gnome Drive tool at least an  reasonably approach to the goal, for now. In the Menu Drive settings is an option to suspend after 5,10,15... sec. 
And it works right after boot.